# Поменять случайные символы в строке местами (UTF8)

Tags: php

Необходимо поменять два близлежащих случайных символа в строке. В начале  работал с массивом символов, но возникли сложности из-за UTF8. Вот что у меня получилось.

```
function swapUTF8($word) {
    $wordLen = mb_strlen($word);

    if ($wordLen < 2) {
        return $word;
    }

    $rand = rand(0, $wordLen - 1);
    $parts[] = mb_substr($word, 0, $rand);
    $parts[] = mb_substr($word, $rand + 1, 1);
    $parts[] = mb_substr($word, $rand, 1);
    $end = $rand + 2;

    if ($end < $wordLen) {
        $parts[] = mb_substr($word, $end);
    }

    return implode('', $parts);
}
```

Но вышло монструозно как-то. Может есть какой-то более простой способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда можно воспользоваться регулярками:

```
<?php
function swapUTF8($word) {
    return preg_replace('%^.{' . rand(0, mb_strlen($word) - 2) . '}\K(.)(.)%u', '$2$1', $word);
}

var_dump(swapUTF8('Привет!'));
```

Вот эта конструкция

```
^.{' . rand(0, mb_strlen($word) - 2) . '}
```

выбирает от начала строки случайное число символов от 0 до длины строки - 2;

`\K` - сбрасывает выбранные символы, чтобы они не попали в замену;

`(.)(.)` - два рядом стоящие символа попадают в 1 и 2 группы захвата.

и в замене `'$2$1'` меняем их местами.1

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0fec23854845fed84731bdadeae3257af139fde2

Comment: Спасибо. Регулярки по памяти и скорости работают у меня быстрей где-то в два раза.

Answer (score 0):

```
$word = substr_replace($word, strrev(substr($word, $rand, 2), $rand, 2)
```

Это без мультибайтов. Но можно попробовать использовать как идею...

Comment: Так вся соль именно в мультибайтах))